# How does website with strange names help SEO?

Tags: seo

Whenever i search for my website name in google to see if someone has given link to my website i see many new strange website name for product called mspy. tThey have hundreds of websites with names like http://57bj9h8o5f618y12.ga/ for example. And new one keeps coming up. They put my website name inside few html tags which is not visible on webpage but maybe just for SEO so that people visit that site from all keywords and they allow download of their app.

The question is does these kind of having different website name with some canned comments at the bottom help SEO? Is it white hat or black hat?

Comment: These are black hat spam sites. Short of too many spam links to your site, these sites are very temporary and should be ignored.

Comment: Thanks for reply @closetnoc, but they have hidden my website name in those pages and i see new temporary website coming up once every week and of course with my website name hidden in some tags. Wont this cause problem for my website? And also what benefit the app owner get if its temporary and black hat?

Comment: Google knows these sites are junk. As well, they come and go so fast that these sites never gain value. It is disturbing. Granted. Not sure what the payoff would be, however, this is nothing new. It has been going on for years.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to me to be a black hat SEO technique.   They appear to be creating a network of sites that exist solely to link to their main site.

If Google finds out about this, Google will likely remove the sites from the search results.   If you want to tell Google about this you can report web spam to Google through search console: https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl=en-gb

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly blackhat SEO. These companies create many websites, each without any actually useful content, which they then link to your sites. The reason for the strange names is that they are randomly generated without human interaction, and also because it helps to bypass some filters.

If the links are not visible when viewed with a browser, that further confirms that these are not legitimate sites or links. The fact that they mention your site may temporarily boost your ranking, but as has already been mentioned, once Google finds out about it, they mark your site.

A good rule of thumb is that if a site or a page isn't of actual value to somebody by itself, such as a well-written original article, then it shouldn't be ranking, and you shouldn't accept links from it.